# ProgressBar displaying as Block style instead of Marquee style

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

I have a strange problem where I set the `Style` property of `ProgressBar` to `Marquee`.

When I compile and deploy to a test machine the `ProgressBar` displays as a `Block` style, which mystifies me because I previously had it as a `Continuous` style before I changed it to `Marquee` but I have commented out all the `ProgressBar.Value` assignment statements. I don't understand how it could be progressing.

I have read that `Marquee` style is not supported unless `Application.RenderWithVisualStyles` is true. Could this be the reason why it is reverting to `Block` style when deployed to another machine?

Comment: Yes, that could/is the reason. You have to link to version 6 of ComCtl32.dll in order to use a marquee progress bar.

Comment: @CodyGray: but should it be reverting back to Block style? I don't understand that.

Comment: What style would you expect it to revert to? Would it be better for it to just not display at all? The segment "block" style is the default.

Comment: But how is the bar progressing when I am not changing the `ProgressBar.Value`?